# Creating FTP user accounts using FTP on server

Tags: php, ftp

Thanks for your wonderful help with my code last week.   I have a VPS running and for my server/website, for each new account I would like to give each user a 50 meg upload space and FTP credentials.  The username and password for the FTP would be unique to each user and the folder would be easily accessible only by them and myself.

I have written a script that can connect to the FTP for my VPS but where would I need to go from here?  Specifically for creating ftp login details for a user that will create a new folder on the ftp for that user and with a limit of 50 meg space.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTP user's use the same login as other logins.

You can create new users using the following command:

```
# adduser -c 'FTP USER Tom' -m tom
```

Then, change tom's password:

```
# passwd tom
```

*Note: For passwd, this is an interactive shell, so you may need to use passthru() or other methods - you can research these yourself.*

Also, these sorts of questions are nothing to do with PHP, and more suited to http://www.superuser.com.

On the PHP side, you can use [`mkdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) for creating directories.

---

To do these things via PHP, you can use [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php): this basically executes shell commands for you. You would use:

```
exec("adduser -c 'FTP USER Tom' -m tom");
```

Make sure you escape your strings correctly, and if you're accepting user input into these commands, make sure you escape them with [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Is it not possible to add a user to FTP via PHP and generate a username and random password for them and set a quota?  Sorry if I seem a little confused.

Comment: @ChrisP Updated with what you require. The random password are simple - there's solutions all over the internet for that. Generate it in PHP, then pass it to your exec when doing your password changes.

Comment: @Jimbo can you answer this question ?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58587781/how-to-create-ftp-in-php

Comment: exec command is highly insecure, Its better not to use it

Comment: No it’s not inherently insecure @FarhatAziz, be careful of falling in the trap of blindly repeating what others tell you without researching yourself because when challenged on it you need to back it up (same goes for “it’s best practice” etc). If you use exec with allowing user input as part of it, for example, then it’s dangerous. How else do you propose to call scripts and command line calls from a programming language?