# How to create ftp in php?

Tags: php, ftp, cpanel

Hello i want to create ftp for particular users.. I have searched on google but nothing found. So i have decided to put question on stackoverflow. I have tried below code but not working at all :-

```
$cpaneluser = "xxxxx"; // i have entered my cpanel user
$cpanelpass = "xxx";   //pwd
$domain = "testing.domain.com"; //here i have entered the domain
$fuser = "testing@domain.com";
$fpass = "mypwd";
$homedir = "/direcctorypath";
$url = "http://$cpaneluser:$cpanelpass@$domain:2082/json-api/cpanel?";
$url .= "cpanel_jsonapi_version=2&cpanel_jsonapi_module=Ftp&cpanel_jsonapi_func=addftp&";
$url .= "user=$fuser&pass=$fpass&homedir=$homedir&quota=0";
var_dump($url);
$result = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump($http_response_header);
if ($result === FALSE) 
die("ERROR: FTP Account not created. Please make sure you passed correct parameters.");
echo $result;
```

[SEE OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46Jts.png)

Every time its output coming FTP Account not created. Please make sure you passed correct parameters..
But i have entered the correct details. i Don't know why its not working.
So later on i have decide lets do with **exec** command but that also not working
Ref Url :- [Creating FTP user accounts using FTP on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524188/creating-ftp-user-accounts-using-ftp-on-server)

```
exec("adduser -c 'testing@domain.com' -m testing123"); // this is not working at all
```

After checking above url i have added the username and password of ftp account. But i have one doubt where i passed the cpanel useranme and password in exec function. Can anyone tell me how to create ftp account of a user. Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the `@` before the `file_get_contents` call. And go read up on how to make `file_get_contents` return the response body even in case of a failed request, so that you can go check what error message might be contained in there.

Comment: @04FS its showing same error  FTP Account not created. Please make sure you passed correct ....... even i have removed @

Comment: That is only half of what I said you should do.

Comment: @04FS its showing NULL

Comment: What _exactly_ is? If you modified your code (and implementing what I asked you to go read up on, would require that), then please show how, by editing it into your question. Or for a maybe bit easier test - what result do you get when you call that URL you are assembling there, directly in your browser …?

Comment: (You should also apply proper URL encoding to the parameter values you are inserting into that URL, otherwise that is asking for trouble; values like a password might easily contains “special characters”.)

Comment: @04FS i have udated the question and added the output

Comment: @04FS yes my password contains special characters like@% and many more

Comment: That’s not what I meant, regarding file_get_contents and checking what the response _body_ actually contains.

Comment: @04FS can you update the code so i can test it